# Scraping URLs from a website that no longer paginates via the URL

Tags: bash, web-scraping

looking for some help to fix a script that I had running.

I had a bash script automated to pull a list of URLs from my government's website where they store proposed bills. It would run through each page by editing ?page=1 in the URL and pull the URLs of every bill it links to. Unfortunately, they've updated the website and they use a different approach for generating content.

[Here's what it used to look like](https://web.archive.org/web/20230302110257/https://www.parliament.nz/en/pb/bills-and-laws/proposed-members-bills/?page=1)

Here's the script I was using:

```
#Pages
pages=$(lynx -nonumbers -dump https://www.parliament.nz/en/pb/bills-and-laws/proposed-members-bills/?page=1 | grep page=[0-9]$)
printf "$pages" | sort -u > /home/links/pages.txt

#Bills
while read p; do
  page="$(lynx -nonumbers -dump $p | grep proposed-members-bills/[A-Za-z0-9])"
  bills="${bills}\n${page}"
done </home/links/pages.txt
printf "$bills" | sort -u > /home/links/bills.txt
sed -i '/./,$!d' /home/links/bills.txt

#PDFs
while read p; do
  pdf="$(lynx -nonumbers -dump $p | grep https://www.parliament.nz/media/)"
  list="${list}\n${pdf}"
done </home/links/bills.txt
printf "$list" | sort -u > /home/links/pdfs.txt
sed -i '/./,$!d' /home/links/pdfs.txt
```

This would collate a list of pages, bills, and PDFs of those bills.

It worked until they updated the website to [look like this](https://bills.parliament.nz/proposed-members-bills).

It no longer uses tags in the URL to adjust page, and I'm no longer sure how I can extract that list of URLs.

They do have an RSS link there, but it is limited to 50 links. There are frequently more than 60 proposed bills.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can get this working again?

Comment: The bane of SPA's, making everything less open =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their new API (`/api/data/search`) is for POST requests, and it supports `pageSize` and `page` arguments.

The request below is using `pageSize: 100`

```bash
curl 'https://bills.parliament.nz/api/data/search' \
  -H 'authority: bills.parliament.nz' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'origin: https://bills.parliament.nz' \
  -H 'referer: https://bills.parliament.nz/proposed-members-bills' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw '{"documentPreset":3,"keyword":null,"selectCommittee":null,"itemType":null,"itemSubType":null,"status":[],"documentTypes":[],"beforeCommittee":null,"billStage":null,"billStages":[],"billTab":null,"billId":null,"includeBillStages":null,"subject":null,"person":null,"parliament":null,"dateFrom":null,"dateTo":null,"datePeriod":null,"restrictedFrom":null,"restrictedTo":null,"terminatedReason":null,"terminatedReasons":[],"column":4,"direction":1,"pageSize":100,"page":1}' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: how do you know that? Could you advice me a source for learning it? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Elkhan Since they still have pagination and the page number is no longer in the query string, I went to the the Dev Tools -> Network Panel -> Filter by: Fetch/XHR.

There I clicked the requests (ignored the *.svg ones), and looked at their content in the "Response" tab.

When I saw that `/search` had the data, I looked in its Payload tab to see the arguments it accepts.

Lastly, I right-clicked the `/search` request, and "Copy" -> Copy as cURL